# Make address/url only available when VPN is connected

Tags: linux, vpn

I'd like to try to make an address/url only available to my PC (Linux) when my VPN is connected and absolutely unavailable when it's not. That means no ping and nothing else. It should act as if the adress is non-existent.

I'm connected over Wifi with a static ip, wlan0. The VPN is tun0. IPv6 is disabled.

How would I do this?

Regards,
Pete

Comment: Make it unavailable to whom?

Comment: Sorry, had a pint already. ;)
Should have been more clearer. Edited. I meant "available to me".

Answer (score 1):

- Automatic execution on VPN connect triggered by the client side (ssh into the box, execute the start/stop command for the service). You use the external IP so you can run it on disconnect. This is easy possible f.e. with OpenVPN (`--up` and `--down`)
- have a script on the server that checks the log of connected VPN clients and triggers a start and stop when a certain client is detected. I would call this the most ugly solution but fully server side option.
- Leave the service running but only listening to the VPN interface on the server. Only works if no one else has access to it -- if not you want to have authentication to the service anyway). That might not be what you want anyway but -- depending on your environment -- might be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Make a static route for the domain and point it through the VPN interface.

```
Windows: route ADD 157.0.0.0 MASK 255.0.0.0  157.55.80.1 METRIC 3 IF 2
            destination^      ^mask          ^gateway    metric^    
                                                          Interface^
Linux: ip route add 23.101.196.141 dev tun0
OR route add -host 23.101.196.141 -interface tun0
```

Comment: Sorry, another thing i forgot to mention: I'm on Linux. And why 157.55.80.1 as gateway and 157.0.0.0 as destination (it's an example, right?).

Comment: Could you explain the IP addresses?

Comment: What's with the "dev vpn0"? Shouldn't it be "dev tun0"?

Comment: When I use "ip route add 23.101.196.141 dev tun0" this happens:

 `route: invalid option -- 'i' 
 BusyBox v1.23.2 (2015-07-14 02:02:29 CEST) multi-call binary.
 
Usage: route [{add|del|delete}]
 
Edit kernel routing tables

        -n      Don't resolve names
        -e      Display other/more information
        -A inet{6}      Select address family
 `
When I use the other one I can't ping the address at all, be it enabled VPN or disabled VPN.

Comment: Sorry, it was the other way around: "route add -host 23.101.196.141 -interface tun0" produced the error.

Comment: Sorry, it's not working! Urgent...